# The function getContextPath must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Tags: jsp-tags

I am using

```
       "<c:out value="${request.getContextPath()}"/>"
```

When I am running this jsp in the tomcat server, I am getting the error as

> The function getContextPath must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Can anyone help in solving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..

using

```
          "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>"
```

solved the error.